# Is there a way to quick compare a weapon with the one in your off hand?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been dual wielding hand crossbows for an Act or so and it's been going very well thus far.  The quivers and crossbows/bows I've come across so far haven't enticed me to switch and my good shield went on my Templar.

I find a number of blue/yellow hand crossbows now and again and I like the comparison to my current weapon.

Is there a way to have it compare to the off hand weapon instead?  Or the lesser of the two equipped weapons?

Alternately would there be a serious disadvantage to putting my best weapon in my off hand and the lesser in the main slot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can press the Alt key to compare the weapon with the off-hand.

Comment: Too bad this toggles the enable/disable view of items on the ground at the same time.