# Can I compare items of both my main hand and off hand to a 2-handed weapon?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know you can perform a quick look [at your off hand by pressing alt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67918/is-there-a-way-to-quick-compare-a-weapon-with-the-one-in-your-off-hand), but is there a  **easier/quick** method to compare both your main hand and off hand weapon to a two handed weapon?  (When I try compare them, it only shows it against my main handed weapon -*besides doing some math*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you dual wield two weapons, and you compare a 2 handed weapon, it automatically compares it to both your main hand and off hand at the same time on the damage gains section.

I equipped a one handed crossbow. compared it to my 2 handed bow for an upgrade of 4197 points of damage. Keeping the same Hand crossbow in my primary I equipped another hand crossbow to my offhand, which increased my damage. Then I compared it to my 2 handed bow again for an increase in if 2940 damage.

It shows the status upgrades versus the main hand but its factoring in both weapons. It also factors in a shields stats if you use one.

**EDIT:**  As of patch 1.0.3, 2 handed weapons are now compared against the weapons in both of your hands.

Comment: It definitely does not consider the effect of removing your off-hand item, at least if that off-hand item is a shield or a wizard source. Equipping a two-hander means getting rid of a shield, but the protection is not factored in. Similarly, two-handers often report that they'd increase your damage, but then don't because of the loss of bonus damage from a source or bonus primary stat from a shield.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been fixed now such that a 2-handed weapon will correctly compare against the items in both of your hands.

Comment: As of patch 1.0.3, 2 handed weapons are now compared against the weapons in both of your hands.